# multiple selection widget

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms

I am using Drupal 8 and I cannot find where the multiple selection checkbox for my taxomomy field is.
[image]

And the result is radio buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have selected field cardinality to one . So its not reflecting checkbox.
Please follow the below steps you can achieve what you asked

1. Go to Structure > Content Type.
2. Select the {{Custom Content Type}} . Click on Manage Fields.
3. Edit the taxonomy Entity Reference field.Click on Field Settings Beside Edit Tab
4. Change Allowed number of values from Limited to Unlimited